# Compare database timestamp value with today's date and get the result in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

HI guys i am trying to get the result from db where my table column **displaytime** is equal to  today's date.

So i am trying to  check that condition by using where. But i don't know hat is the problem it showing query is wrong

Here is my model:

```
function getDashboardContent() {
    $today = date('Y-m-d H-i');
    $this->db->select('cd.details,g.displaytime');
    $this->db->where('cd.typeofinfo', 2);
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(g.displaytime,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i')", $today );
    $this->db->from('contentdetails cd');
    $this->db->join('content c', 'c.id = cd.contentid');
    $this->db->join('group_content gc', 'gc.contentid = c.id');
    $this->db->join('groups g', 'g.id = gc.groupid');
   $this->db->order_by('cd.id',"DESC");
    $this->db->limit('1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    print_r($query);
    exit;
    return $query->result();
  }
```

Here is my error:

```
    Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2018-07-27 12-02' ORDER BY `cd`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1' at line 7

SELECT `cd`.`details`, `g`.`displaytime` FROM `contentdetails` `cd` JOIN `content` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `cd`.`contentid` JOIN `group_content` `gc` ON `gc`.`contentid` = `c`.`id` JOIN `groups` `g` ON `g`.`id` = `gc`.`groupid` WHERE `cd`.`typeofinfo` = 2 AND DATE_FORMAT(g.displaytime,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i') '2018-07-27 12-02' ORDER BY `cd`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone help me what is the exact problem and what mistake i have done

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change datetime to timestamp and then compare like this

```
$this->db->where("TO_SECONDS(g.displaytime)", strtotime($today) );
```

Comment: hi i have one doubt may i ask

Answer (score 0):

i have solve my problem by changing this line

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(g.displaytime,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i')!=", "$today" );
```

**TO**

```
 $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(g.displaytime,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i') = '" . $today . "'");
```